# CMake -- CUDA compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: cmake, cuda, clion

I am working on a small library that makes use of CUDA, however I cannot seem to make CMake work when I run it from the command line, even though my IDE (CLion) uses CMake to comile the program succesfully.

I have scoured the internet for ages trying to solve this, though with nothing making much of a difference. I have got CUDA 11.1 and CMake 3.17.3, and both are accessable from the command line.

CLion is able to compile the code perfectly, and everything works as expected, however when I run CMake from the command line, it gives the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Desktop\Rapid\Temporary\Rapid\build> cmake ..
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.1.105
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.1/bin/nvcc.exe
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.1/bin/nvcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.17.3/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:46 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.1/bin/nvcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make.exe cmTC_2c864/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_2c864.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_2c864.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2c864.dir/main.cu.o
    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.1/bin/nvcc.exe" -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler    -x cu -c /cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/main.cu -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_2c864.dir/main.cu.o
    c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:/cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/main.cu': No such file or directory
    main.cu
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_2c864.dir/build.make:86: CMakeFiles/cmTC_2c864.dir/main.cu.o] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_2c864/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/penci/OneDrive/Desktop/Rapid/Temporary/Rapid/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Sorry for the wall of text, but I'm not sure why this doesn't work in the command line, when it does in CLion.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Rapid LANGUAGES CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/rapid/graphics/GLFW)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/rapid/graphics/GLFW/lib64)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcompiler /openmp")

SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

add_executable(Rapid main.cu)

set_target_properties(
        Rapid
        PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

target_link_libraries(Rapid cublas glfw3 gdi32 opengl32)
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this issue would be greatly appreciated, as I have spent days trying to fix this, but nothing online seems to work.

Comment: Can't you analyze the output log of the build inside CLion and look for differences between the two builds?

Comment: @talonmies The CLion output just says that it all works. It gives the same path to ```nvcc```, but instead of saying ```broken``` it says ```works``` and continues on until it is finished. I'm not sure what would be causing this to happen.

Comment: I've played around with it some more and if I use the CLion version of CMake, it does actually work correctly, but only when generating files for Visual Studio. These files don't actually compile though, which is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Googling some things that seemed completely unrelated to the issue, I discovered that my Cygwin64 install of CMake was not setup to use Visual Studio generators.

To fix the issue, I needed to put the Visual Studio install of CMake into the `PATH` environment variable, but it needed to be *above* the Cygwin64 `bin` directory. This meant that running the `cmake` command from the command line would refer to the Visual Studio install, and not the Cygwin64 install, allowing it to work correctly.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future too